# Grepping CSV files and outputting to another file

Tags: csv, terminal, grep

I have a very very large CSV file. An example of 1 line in the file is:

```
1880,Mary,F,7065
```

I want to be able to filter my file by taking all the entries that meet certain criteria and put them in a separate file. For example, I want to be able to do something like:

Take all the lines where the third entry is "Mary" and copy those lines into a new line.

Any idea of how I would do this using grep?

Comment: it entirely depends on your actual criteria, and the complexity of doing so varies. is that exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First a bit better test file with a positive and a negative line (for *third entry is "Mary"*):

```
$ cat file
1880,Mary,F,7065
1880,Mary,Mary,7065
```

*all the lines where the third entry is "Mary"* using `grep`:

```
$ grep "^\([^,]*,\)\{2\}Mary" file
1880,Mary,Mary,7065
```

If you'd like more rules, you'd use OR (`|`), for example to get the previous OR just `F` on the line:

```
$ grep "\(^\([^,]*,\)\{2\}Mary\|F\)" file
```

I'd use awk over `grep`, though:

```
$ awk -F, '$3=="Mary" || /F/' file
```